# Is it possible to perform unit testing on dll's methods without an executable during build process?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, dll

I have 63 DLL's with various C++ methods in each. I want to validate the output of some of the methods with fixed input values. I'm wondering if it is possible to do unit testing in the DLL itself during <strike>*compilation*</strike> build process.

So, the <strike>*compilation*</strike> build of DLL gives the results of the Unit Testing in the Output window of Visual Studio.

I know that I can validate this scenario by creating executable file and calling the methods. But, is it possible without executable file?

Comment: You can use [`RunDLL32`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) as the executable file provided that you have a `void CALLBACK
  UnitTest(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);` method in your DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said - testing "during compilation" does not make sense, so I'm assuming you mean testing during the build process, which is different and of course possible using post build steps etc.

You don't specify which version of Visual Studio you use, but if you have VS2012, there is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx) that describes exactly how to do what you describe. See the link for the full instructions, I've attached a partial screenshot below

[image: unit tests for unmanaged dll]

Comment: Thanks for the link. It helped me get started.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait compilation to complete so that there are no compilation error in the code.

In the post-build event you can add batch files which will run your unit test modules and validate the binaries generated after compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Taking your question verbatim, the answer is "no", because you can't test a DLL when you haven't even finished compiling it. Also, you need some kind of executable to load that DLL, so either you load it with a scripting language (Python with ctypes comes to mind) or you create an executable.

Calling that from a post-compile step in Visual Studio, as suggested by shivakumar is probably the only way to get the results into the output window. I personally prefer running this from an external build script, but I'm also cross-compiling a lot and I can't run things from a post-compile step there. This also makes it easier to debug the unit tests when something fails.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a thing that does not make sense.  When you say "compiling" that means a very specific thing: invoking the compiler, before invoking the linker.  But C++ code (and C++ unit tests) do not work like that.  The compiler must finish compiling both your production code and your tests, and the object files must then be linked into libraries, executables, or both.  A test framework must then execute the test code which calls your production code in order to get results.  None of these steps are optional in C++.

Instead, you probably intended to ask if you could run the unit tests as part of the build (not compile).  And the answer to that is an emphatic "yes!"

I'm guessing that your solution is likely structured into 63 or more individual DLL projects.  For each production DLL you are going to test, such as Foo.DLL, I recommend you add a new FooTest project, with the unit test code added to the FooTest project.  In FooTest, create a project dependency upon the Foo project, which will force FooTest to build after building Foo.  In the FooTest project you would have two kinds of code modules: classes containing your unit tests, and a FooTest.cpp that would house the main() entrypoint of the FooTest.EXE program, invoking the testing framework, and outputting the results to the console.

Create your FooTest.cpp so that it's a console program.  If you format your test executable's output so that it matches the output of the Visual Studio compiler, as in "filename.cpp(lineNo) : error:  description of failure", Visual Studio will automatically navigate to the file and line if you click on it.  Unit test frameworks such as CppUnit may already have a "CompilerOutputter" class that will properly format the output to match your compiler's errors.

In your FooTest project, you also need to set the input to the FooTest linker so that it can link in the production code you are trying to test.  In the properties of the FooTest project, go to the Linker/Input tab and add the path to your Foo project's OBJ files to the Additional Dependencies.  The line I use looks like this:  $(SolutionDir)Foo\Debug\obj*.obj

In the Build Events properties of the FooTest project, invoke your new FooTest.EXE as a post-build step.  Then, every time you click build, your code will be built and your unit tests will be executed.  The project dependency will ensure that if you change your Foo code, you will compile, link, and execute the FooTest tests.  And the console output ensures that your test results will appear as clickable output in your IDE.

You could create 63 separate unit test executables, or you could create one all-encompassing unit test executable.  That's entirely your choice.  If you are looking to make the builds and links happen quicker, you will probably want to have the separate executables; even though it's a bit more individual configuration work, you do it only once, and after that you retain the benefits of quick builds for small changes.

Now you're ready to do some serious coding.

Comment: Hmmm, I consider linking a part of compiling, not separate to it. Same with preprocessing sources. I don't think this is strictly used to mean what you say. Anyhow, there's a fault here: If you set a dependency (FooTest depends on Foo), VS will automatically link Foo into FooTest. Adding the object files should then be completely useless, it could even be harmful since it links the content twice then.

Comment: It's critical to make the distinction when you're trying to understand what's going on.  For example, you missed the point that the two different invocations of the linker are producing two executables from one set of object files - the Foo.DLL and the FooTest.EXE.  You should also know that linking never alters the object files, it only copies their contents into the product's binary and assigns addresses.  Another good approach is to build the production code into a static library (which you do not link), then have the two projects link Foo.DLL and FooTest.exe with the library.

Comment: Okay, that part indeed wasn't clear to me. I expected the test application to link to the DLL like all other applications and not statically. Also, if I had wanted to statically link, I would have included the source files into both the DLL and EXE projects, to avoid issues from linking things compiled with different compiler settings. Further, I wouldn't want to dllexport symbols from the EXE. What's the rationale for your particular setup? Why not use the DLL?

Comment: There are two big advantages to linking with the same .OBJs. One is you're not wasting time compiling twice; the other is you're testing exactly the code you're planning to deploy. For your other question, unit testing is about testing the code at a fine-grained module interface, not at the higher level that most DLLs expose.  You can and should test the DLLs thru the DLL interface, but that's generally higher level than unit tests.

Comment: Unit-testing is not by definition white-box testing. It can be, but it can also be block-box testing of e.g. a DLL. But thanks for clarifying why you are doing things the way you do it, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Actually, the definition of unit testing is "testing the smallest possible unit of code", and is white box testing. Black box testing of a DLL based on its specifications is called functional testing.